# ng-select only showing one result from array

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm displaying a list of items from an array using ng-option, however, only the first item from the array is displaying.

HTML -

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let result of selected">
      {{result.medications.items[0].name}}
   </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

[image: items logged]

Comment: What do you expect to be shown here? Are the items to show in the items Array? Then you have to use `ngFor="let item of medications.items` ... What is in selected? Only one item can be selected, so only one should render, right?

Comment: Your ngFor isn't on medications... you want to use  `selected.medications`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let res of medications.items">
      {{res.name}}
   </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

You need to loop over the items in medications and display the name of each item as demonstrated above...

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate through `medications.items`.

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let result of medications.items">
      {{result.name}}
   </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let result of selected.medications.items">
      {{result.name}}
   </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```